# How to open all Safari history at once?

Tags: macos, mac, safari, history, browser-history

I was navigating through a website but I forgot which one was it now going back to Safari History and searching for the website is a painful thing to do so I was asking is there anyway to open all your safari history with one click?

Comment: What do you mean by 'open all your safari history'?  You stated you were already searching thru your history for the website.

Comment: @fsb see I have over 5000 websites in my search history for today which falls under a tab:- Today> Your History so I simply want open all visited websites under today at once since while holding shift clicking all the websites is not working so....I don't know how to do that

Comment: Pressing Cmd-Y and then using the search field might help here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use Command + Shift + T and you will reopen the last closed browser tab or window.

Or choose an option labeled Reopen All Windows from Last Session in Safari’s History menu (at the top).

Outside of that, there is no direct way to open multiple tabs/sessions like that on Safari.

Comment: I know this option but it only works when numerous tabs were open before quitting Safari and if some tabs were open and some were closed before quitting Safari the close tabs don't restore so I simply want to open my entire history/visited websites within the last few days at once

Comment: Ok. All I can think of is to try out these two extensions and see if they can help. Fetching - https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=io.fetching-V2EEZ7SHU9 and History Search - https://safari-extensions.apple.com/details/?id=net.historysearch-PER954UH2X They both save and log your browser history.

Comment: Both didn't worked!

Comment: Then I don't know what else can work. Session manager for Chrome is the best for this type of stuff. Safari hasn't applied it yet.

Answer (score 6):

1. Go to the Safari menu "History" and click on "Show all history"
2. Find the lines you're interested in and highlight them
3. Drag these lines into the tab bar and they will all open in separate tabs

Comment: This really ought to be the right answer. Unless of course it's only after the most recently closed session but I ran into the problem with it being greyed out. This is what was key though.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create new folder anywhere (in Desktop for example)
2. Go to history and command-click on the pages you want to open to select them
3. Drag them to the new folder (created in step 1 )
4. <kbd>Cmd-A</kbd> to select all in folder.
5. <kbd>Cmd-O</kbd> to open them all.

I hope this solve your problem.

Comment: What does "command+pages" mean in step 2?

Comment: command is the key to select the pages history folder.

Comment: It's not clear what the user needs to do here. Command-drag the links to the folder created in step 1?

Comment: yes,  pressing command is to allow you to choose multiple pages from history